# Difference between coherent and incoherent energy transfer (e.g. in photosynthesis)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, energy, biophysics, coherence

Several authors distinguish between incoherent and coherent when describing the energy transfer mechanism that forms the basis for photosynthesis. 
(e.g. [Clegg & Sener 2010](https://www.ks.uiuc.edu/~melih/Clegg2010.pdf) and [Keren & Paltiel 2018](https://www.cell.com/trends/plant-science/abstract/S1360-1385(18)30049-9)). Incoherent energy transfer is also sometimes equated with FRET (Forster Resonance Energy Transfer) or with hopping.

Can you help explain the difference? In each case, there is nonradiative (near-field) energy transfer from donor to acceptor mediated by a coupling, right? What is special then about coherent energy transfer on top of that?